# Android logical if .. else operators

Tags: android, logical-operators

Is there a similar construct in Android / Java programming as there is in PHP:

```
Condition ? [if true, do this] : [else do this]
```

Sometimes code is much easier to read that way than with endless if..else clauses,
so I'd be surprised if Java / Android wouldn't offer something similar?

Comment: post comment: sorry, I digged through many pages of online documentation, but didn't find that. If I would have found it, I would certainly not have asked here, but then of course you guys can't know that. Hopefully this post if of use for someone else, as the answers were for me. Thanks for that (and it would be kewl to stop punishing me with even more downvotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and the syntax is exactly the same: `Condition ? [if true, do this] : [else do this]`

Comment: oh .. cool 8-) I didn't expect that, thought it didn't work before. Will give it another try now, thanks!

Comment: Note that `"do this"` can for instance *not* be a call to a void-method. The ternary operator is *not* syntactic sugar for `if ... else ...`.

Answer (score 2):

First some important terminology:

- **Statements** are instructions of what to do, such as `System.out.println("hello");`, `Thread.sleep(1000);`
- **Expressions**, such as `x + y` or `foo() - bar()` evaluate to values.

You need to understand these terms and keep them apart.

The conditional control structure `if (a) { b } else { c }` is a **statement**.

The ternary operator `a ? b : c` is an **expression** (which, just as in PHP evaluates to `b` if `a` evaluates to true, and to `c` otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

In Java there also exists the shorthand for an `if-then-else` statement: take a look at the [Conditional Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) chapter to have a better understanding.

To be clearer, as @aioobe suggested: though it is considered in particular contexts to be a shorthand to an `if-then-else` structure, the **`? :`** is not a statement, but a **ternary conditional operator** or **ternary operator**.

Comment: *In Java there also exists the shorthand for an if-then-else statement* -- Are you referring to the ternary `a ? b : c` operator?

Comment: *[...] shorthand for an if-then-else statement [...]*, the `? :` construct is not a statement, so you may want to revise your wording.